# npm ERR! missing script: (insert anything here) on Vue.js app after moving folder

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm in the process of moving a Vue.js app into a new repository, extracting it from it's old host.

At this point I have literally copied the app from one folder to another but it won't build. It builds fine in the first folder but not in the second.

As soon as I type `npm run build` / `npm run build-app-only` (or anything else for that matter) I get this...

`npm ERR! missing script: vue-cli-service`

or

`node-sass is not recognised as an internal or external command`

Here's the scrips part of my package.json....

```
"scripts": {
    "serve-vstudio": "npm run messaging-css && vue-cli-service serve",
    "serve": "npm run messaging-css && vue-cli-service serve --port 8080",
    "build": "npm run messaging-css && vue-cli-service build",
    "build-app-only": "npm run vue-cli-service build",
    "build-debug": "npm run messaging-css && vue-cli-service build --mode staging",
    "test": "vue-cli-service test:unit \"\\.*\\.spec\\.js$\" --testPathIgnorePatterns=\"\\long/.*\\.spec\\.js$\"",
    "test-all": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" vue-cli-service test:unit \"\\.*\\.spec\\.js$\"",
    "test-long": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" vue-cli-service test:unit \"\\long/.*\\.spec\\.js$\"",
    "test-ci": "vue-cli-service test:unit \"\\.*\\.spec\\.js$\" --testPathIgnorePatterns=\"\\long/.*\\.spec\\.js$\"",
    "test-clear": "jest --clearCache",
    "test-watch": "vue-cli-service test:unit \"\\.*\\.spec\\.js$\" --testPathIgnorePatterns=\"\\long/.*\\.spec\\.js$\" --watch",
    "test-watch-all": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" vue-cli-service test:unit \"\\.*\\.spec\\.js$\" --watch",
    "test-watch-long": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" vue-cli-service test:unit \"\\long/.*\\.spec\\.js$\" --watch",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "view-cfg": "vue inspect > standard.config.js",
    "watch": "vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch",
    "messaging-css-ecofurb": "node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/ecofurb.scss -o public/schemes/ecofurb/css --output-style compressed & node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/ecofurb.scss -o ../plan-builder/schemes/ecofurb/css --output-style compressed",
    "messaging-css-oxfordshire": "node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/oxfordshire.scss -o public/schemes/oxfordshire/css --output-style compressed && node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/oxfordshire.scss -o ../plan-builder/schemes/oxfordshire/css --output-style compressed",
    "messaging-css-parity": "node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/parity.scss -o public/schemes/parity/css --output-style compressed && node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/parity.scss -o ../plan-builder/schemes/parity/css --output-style compressed",
    "messaging-css-radbot": "node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/radbot.scss -o public/schemes/radbot/css --output-style compressed & node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/radbot.scss -o ../plan-builder/schemes/radbot/css --output-style compressed",
    "messaging-css-warmersussex": "node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/warmersussex.scss -o public/schemes/warmersussex/css --output-style compressed && node-sass src/scss/schemes/messaging/warmersussex.scss -o ../plan-builder/schemes/warmersussex/css --output-style compressed",
    "messaging-css": "npm run messaging-css-ecofurb && npm run messaging-css-oxfordshire && npm run messaging-css-parity && npm run messaging-css-radbot && npm run messaging-css-warmersussex"
  },
,
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^5.0.0",
    "arg-guard": "^1.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "breakpoint-sass": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "delay": "^4.3.0",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "onload-function-stack": "^1.2.0",
    "susy": "^3.0.5",
    "uri-path-manager": "^1.0.4",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "vee-validate": "^2.1.3",
    "vue": "2.6.7",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.17.2",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-router": "3.0.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.20.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "window-wrapper": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/server-test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.12.0",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001059",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
    "flush-promises": "^1.0.2",
    "happy-dom": "^0.14.1",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "jest-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-url": "^8.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue-server-renderer": "2.6.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.7"
  }
```

I am running from the root folder, where package.json is located.

I have tried making another copy in a different folder (that breaks too).

I've tried manually running `npm i` again (even though I copied all of the files over).

I've scoured the internet but all solutions on this seem to revolve around the script not being found being a custom script but that's not the case - My defined scripts are being found fine but the calls out from the scripts themselves don't seem to work anymore since the move.

Comment: What happens if you remove `node_modules`, install the dependencies again, and rerun the command?

Comment: It seems that your vue-cli bin is attached to that directory, you can run vue-cli-service command on your terminal?

as the doc says: Inside a Vue CLI project, @vue/cli-service installs a binary named vue-cli-service. You can access the binary directly as vue-cli-service in npm scripts, or as ./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service from the terminal.

do you have that dependency in your project `@vue/cli-service`? check if it's on the new folder that you created inside `node_modules`

Comment: @WesleyGuirra or simply `npx vue-cli-service` (it will first look in `node_modules`)

Comment: Yes it will run from `node_modules`, but the dependency need to be listed on package.json before npm install command.

Comment: All the dependencies are listed and present and correct - I excluded them for brevity buit will add

Comment: In the end I solved this by deleting everything, going back to scratch and copying over fresh and it worked - when I was moving things about I'd initially placed the files into an SPA Harness .net Core project - I think that may have done something / changed some config somewhere. Putting them in a new fresh cold folder worked.

Comment: I wish I could provide a more concrete reason as to what broke and what fixed it, but I can't.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about `scripts` section, but about `dependencies`.

Install it globaly as shown [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html):

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
# OR
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

if still doesn't work add dev dependency:

```
npm i @vue/cli-service -D
# OR 
yarn add @vue/cli-service -D
```

Comment: These are all installed and listed - updated above to show.

Comment: @KeithJackson try full path `./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service`

Comment: It's not specific - every single thing wasn't running - 'vue-cli-service', 'jest', 'node-sass' - All of them were inexplicably not working where they worked fine in a different root folder. My best guess was a corrupting config file somewhere or something that got stripped out when the files went into the harness project.

Comment: As far as I understand, you completely reinstalled the modules, so that everything should be working, the main file `package.json` and `package.lock.json` which stores the versions - these two files are quite enough. if you put it on github try cloning.

Answer (score 0):

"watch": "vue-cli-service serve --open"
Just add this line to your scripts in the package. json file in the script objects the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).